# Azure DevOps Pipeline CI good pratice when creating it's own pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using Azure DevOps Pipeline for CI and CD (Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment). I realize there are many ways to define de build Pipeline. Let me explain with examples:

For one of my project I started by creating 2 Pipelines. Both targeting the same repository, same solution but one for Desktop build and the other one for Web API build (publish method).

The I realize this take twice the time because each pipeline definition work independently. Also for all my test I decided to merge these 2 pipelines as 2 agent in one pipeline.

Then I decided to merge my 2 agent in one and move only my build publish in this unique agent. So now I have one pipeline with one agent but 2 build tasks.

Is it correct. For now it meets my needs but what about testing, good practice for reason I still ignore.

For example my to 2 build are copying the files in a unique drop artifact. I'm thinking to create 2 artifacts. What are the rules?

I don't know what are the best practice or the reasons to design his build definition.